# How can one prevent arbitrary string indexing in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

This code compiles, and I don't want it to:

```
declare const foo: { x: number }
const bar = foo['y']
```

The type of `bar` is inferred to be `any`. I want `foo['y']` to be treated the same as `foo.y`, which would be a type error. Is there any way to accomplish this? I'm compiling with TypeScript 2.6 and `--strict`.

Comment: Are you sure?  This is flagged as an error with `--noImplicitAny` which is part of `--strict`.  I can't reproduce.  TypeScript 2.6 is still in pre-release, so I don't know what exact version you're using.  Can you triple check?

Comment: What the content of your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Aha, someone snuck `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` into our `tsconfig.json`! That was the issue, thanks!